# select a column name with a variable

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a table with 10 columns ,with names: cost201907,  cost201906, cost201905 ......

I want to put in a variable the today month and year:   a = 201907

```
define a = to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy')|| to_char(SYSDATE, 'mm') from dual;

SELECT &a;

output: a = 201907
```

My goal is to select a column using this variable.

Each month run a script that give me today's date in a variable,

and after use it to select the most recent columns with a select statement,  such as:

```
Select  'cost'||a  from Table1.
```

Probably i ll use PL/SQL but still cant find a way. Please help me.

Comment: If you really want to do this, Alex Poole already gave you a good way, but it never hurts to have another option. So since you said you will be doing this in PLSQL, you could look into EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, where you will basically create a string containing the SQL QUERY with whichever variables you want, and have some place bound for the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to insert the query into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a substitution variable, but you need to populate it slightly differently, form the column name properly.

At the moment you're using `define`, which gives `a` the value of the entire string you set; then your select gets that whole string as a replacement, which you can see with `set verify on`:

```
SELECT &a;

old:SELECT &a
new:SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy')|| to_char(SYSDATE, 'mm') from dual

TO_CHA
------
201907
```

Then when you do

```
Select  'cost'a  from Table1;
```

you are selecting the text literal 'cost', and giving that column expression the alias `a` - completely unrelated to your variable; so you'll see output like:

```
A   
----
cost
cost
cost
...
```

with one output row for every row in your table.

Instead of your define, use the `column ... new_value ...` option to make the result of a dummy query available as a substitution variable for a later one:

```
column a new_value a;

select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMM') as a from dual;

A     
------
201907

select  cost&a  from table1;

old:select  cost&a  from table1
new:select  cost201907  from table1

COST201907
----------
        42
...
```

You can wrap the dummy query in a `set termout off` and `... on` pair, though you still seem to need to run your script from a file with `@` to make that take effect properly. And you can `set verify off` to hide the old/new display once you're happy with it.

Comment: I understand the concept. So it will ask me everytime what column i need, right?

Comment: Also a found that there is another way to transpose the column to rows and use a variable. But how i can transpose the tabe as each column has thousands of rows?

Comment: It won't ask you anything, the dummy query works out the date part of the column name. I'm not sure what you mean about transposing. This will gives you the current-month column for all rows in your table. (This is a horrible data model by the way; why do you have one column per month, instead of one row per month?)

Comment: @gellis - are you running all of this at once as a script (F5), or as separate statements? It would still prompt if you ran the query on its own; so it needs to be run as a script.